# Yii2 with relation + join 2 tables

Tags: php, mysql, activerecord, yii2

I'm new - beginner in Yii2 framework and need help.
I have tables:

e_rooms:

### id | name

e_items:

### id|name|id_unit|id_department|price|quantity

e_units:

### id|name

e_departments:

### id|name

In model Rooms.php

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'items_in_room' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Items', 'id_room'),
    );
}
public function getItems()
{
   return $this->hasMany(Items::className(), ['id_room' => 'id'])
}
```

In RoomsController.php:

```
public function actionView($id)
{
    return $this->render('view', [
        'model' => $this->findModel($id),
        'room_items' => $this->findModel($id)->items,
        ]);
}
```

In view.php:

```
GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => new ArrayDataProvider([
            'allModels' => $room_items,
            'pagination' => [
                'pageSize' => 100,
            ],
            'sort' => [
                'attributes' => ['number_reference', 'name', 'price'],
            ],
        ]),

        //'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
[.......]
```

This show all Items in this Room - it's OK, but how i can join table e_units and e_departments to get name unit and name department instead od ID's ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your Item model define the relations to Unit and and Department

```
public function getUnit(){
    return $this->hasOne(Unit::className(), ['id' => 'id_unit']);
}
public function getDepartment(){
    return $this->hasOne(Department::className(), ['id' => 'id_department']);
}
```

you can use them in gridview as columns like so:

```
GridView::widget([
    /* ... */
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        'id',             // item id
        'name',           // item name
        'department.name' 
        'unit.name'
    ],
    /* ... */
```

to avoid excesive queries in the view you can load these relations when building the `room_items` array

```
 'room_items' => $this->findModel($id)->getItems()->with(['unit', 'department'])->all()
```

on a side note, do checkout yii2 [guidelines for schema design](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/227/guidelines-for-good-schema-design/), (old yii documentation, but the same guides apply)
you should have a good understanding on when and why you should use single/plural naming for tables, models and relations

Comment: This method dramaticaly increase of SQL query to database. Each Items generate two additional query. If in Room have example 30 Items - this generate above 60 queries. Maybe better is use LEFT JOIN, but how this make in Yii2?

Comment: added a ->with() call to the reply, to eager-load relation data.

Comment: Thanks again, You amazing!

Comment: I have next problem:
In detailed view _Items_ need show **name** instead od **id** of Room (in table _e_items_ I have column: _id_room_, _id_previous_room_).
How this I can do?

Comment: apply the same process again

Answer (score 0):

Same process not work:(

```
 table e_items (id, name, id_room, id_previous_room, id_unit,  id_department,....)
 table e_rooms (id, name)
 table e_units (id, name)
 table e_departments (id, name)
```

In view items/view.php I need like this:
Item:

```
id => id
name => name
id_room => name_of_room
id_previous_room => name_of_room
id_unit => name_unit
id_department => name_department
```

I don't know how make like above....
How in ItemsController make relations without SQL query on each id of unit,room, etc.